# View does not load and session attribute missing after reload

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-session

I have built this Vaadin application with Spring Boot and have a JWT based solution for security.

When the user authenticates into the application, I store the token in `VaadinSession`.

The problem I am facing is one specific view appears completely blank when the page loads. It takes a manual page refresh to appear in entirety and completely normal, except my `VaadinSession` that is now empty of the attribute I had just stored, and the user is back to unauthenticated state again.

The question is, this view is just like any other view, but why should it take two refreshes to appear, and why does the `VaadinSession` get invalidated?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: If your view is empty, check the dev-console in your browser for errors (or if the request dead-locks).  And if there is no error on the server side, ramp up the logging and make sure, that you are not facing a logic problem (e.g. something throws silently or an early return etc).